# Explicitly make the active transaction log full

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have to make the active transaction log full to test some scenarios in my application. Is there any hack/shortcut available to make it full?

I tried updating a table with more than 480 million records but was of no help

Comment: Assuming this is a throw-away test server (such as in a Docker container), shrink it and turn off filegrowth first?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS:

1. Right click on the DB you need to paralyse -> Properties
2. Go to "Files"
3. Find the line with File Type = 'ROWS'
4. Set it's size to 4 MB (it's minimal required file size) in the "Size (MB)" column.
5. Click on the "..." for the "Autogrowth/Maxsize" column and uncheck the "Enable Autogrowth" check box.

now do some kill-dml